# iMac with OS X 10.5.8 - can we upgrade?

Tags: macos, osx-leopard, imac

We have an iMac with v10.5.8
2 GHZ intel core dual 
1 GB int memory 512/512
667 MHz
DDR2 SDRAM

Can we upgrade to just Snow Leopard, or can we go to Lion?

Comment: Why do you look at the lion specification?

Comment: -1 This question does not show any research effort. *Apple.com » Support » Mac » OS X Lion » [Installation and Recovery](http://www.apple.com/support/lion/installrecovery/) » "To use Lion, make sure your computer has the following: Mac computer with an Intel Core 2 Duo, Core i3, Core i5, Core i7, or Xeon processor"*

Answer (score 1):

Because intel core duo has no x64 abilities you can only use osx snow leopard. Lion and Mountain Lion requires an x64 CPU.